# Using conda when systemwide python is available

Tags: python, macos, pip, conda

I'm working on OS X and have initially installed python3 with homebrew, together with some packages (numpy, scipy, matplotlib, ipython) that I installed using pip.

Is it now possible to install conda/anaconda and create isolated conda environments that are independent of my system-wide installation?

Comment: Yes, this is the whole point of conda. Are you having trouble with this?

Comment: To be honest I just wasn't sure about how to proceed best. I'm used to system-wide installations (either using a package manager like apt, or by using something like cvmfs on a cluster where I'm working remote in a terminal). At my current work, a lot of people are using Anaconda, but are also usually working in Windows. I wanted to be able to use "my way" of just firing up an ipython notebook or an ipython console to start coding, but wasn't sure if it's the same in conda and whether I can still use conda in case it's a requirement in a project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is. Anaconda will install python 2.7.15 or python 3.6.5, but you can create conda environments for any version of python you wish. The command`conda create -n yourenv python=3.4` creates a conda environment tied to python 3.4, for example. the Anaconda documentation has more options for creating conda environments which may be helpful in your particular case.